# Community Navigation LWC in flow component not working

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning-community, navigation

I am building flow component in lwc that communicate with visualforce page. This flow is used in experience cloud and in some conditions I want to direct the user to home page. but the navigation is not working. Anyone can help me understand why? The row 'navigation required' print to console

LWC

```
 listenMessage = (message) => {
console.log('message');
if (message.data.name === 'paymentCompleted') {
      ....
  }
} else if (message.data.name === 'iframeHeight') {
  ....
} else if (message.data.name === 'paymentCanceled'){
    if(this.cartId)
    {
      console.log('navigation required');
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        Attributes: {
          name: 'Home'
          // recordId: this.cartId,
          // objectType: 'WebCart'
        }
      })
    }
}
```

};
VF

```
<apex:page controller="CyberSourceRedirectController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStyleSheets="false">

<p>{!errorMessage}</p>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function () {
        if ('{!isInvalidData}' == true) {
            console.log('isInvalidData true');
        } else {
            var lexOrigin = "{!$Site.BaseUrl}/s/checkout";
            var payload = 'paymentCanceled';
            var message = {
                name: "paymentCanceled",
                payload: payload
            };
            parent.postMessage(message, '*');
        }
    };
</script>
```

</apex:page>